# Marauders dilemma algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm making this repost after the earlier one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306193/travelling-salesman-with-profit) with more details.

PROBLEM : 
The problem consists of a marauder who has to travel to different cities spread over a map. The starting location is known. Each city has a fixed loot associated with it. The aim of marauder is to travel across various nature of terrain. By nature of terrain, I mean there is a varied cost of travel between each pair of cities. He has to maximize the booty gained.

**What we have done:** 
We have generated an adjacancy matrix (booty-path cost in place for each node) and then employed a heuristic analysis. It gave some output which is reasonable.

Now, **the problem** now is that each city has few or more vehicles in them, which can be bought (by paying) and can be used to travel. What vehicle does in actual is that it reduces the path cost. Once a vehicle is bought, it remains upto the time when next vehicle is bought. It is to upto to decide whether to buy the vehicle or not and how.

I need help at this point. How to integrate the idea of vehicle into what we already have? Plus, any further ideas which may help us to maximize the profit. I can post the code, if required. Thanks!

Comment: How is the cost reduced? Is it a fixed percentage reduction or do you get a whole new set of costs?

Comment: Percentage reduced. Say it will become 0.9 of what it would be by foot (that is the normal method of transport)

Comment: He's a marauder, he doesn't pay for vehicles! I'll probably get a downvote for this, but totally worth it!

Comment: This isn't clear at all. @Vivek, please could you explain with an example? What are the marauder's choices, and what are trying to optimise?

Comment: His ultimate aim is to maximise his profit or loot as said. Now, since buying vehicles reduce the cost of travel compared to traveling normal, so If it possible that he gains more than what he paid for buying the vehicle, he will buy it.
He can skip cities as well, if the cost of travel is more than the loot gained. Similar to TSP with proifts!

Comment: does a vehicle works only from the city where it was bought to the next one? isn't it just a simple preprocessing of a graph? you have A -> B costs x, and 2 vehicles that change cost to y and z. Select the minimal cost and consider only it.

Comment: No. The vehicle would now work for all our travels.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it would be to have a directed edge bearing the cost of the vehicle towards a duplicate graph with the reduced costs. You can even make it so that the reduction is finer than just a percentage if you want to.

The downside is that this will probably increase the size of the graph a lot (as many copies as you have different vehicles, plus the links between them), and if your heuristic is not optimal, you may have to modify it so that it considers the new edge positively.

Comment: I guess so. Because the types of vehicle can be large enough (say 10 or 20).

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to implement as it just consists of a preprocessing of the graph. Then you could see if the extra cost is actually an issue. It should also tell you if the heuristic needs to be modified.

Comment: With our present knowledge, we finding it a little difficult! Please help

Comment: Ok here's an outline: 1. Generate the graph duplicates (one per vehicle), keeping track of the correspondence. 2. Add directed edges from the places where you can buy vehicles to the corresponding places in the corresponding subgraph, with the cost associated to that vehicle. 3. Run your existing algorithm on the augmented graph

Comment: The problem is that, we have to pay for buying vehicle. So until unless our investment is not recovered, why should we buy a vehicle at next city and whether buying vehicle is profitable or not is only known if we know the full path I guess. (For example we invest 300, but gain only 150 extra due to path cost), so it is not preferable!

Comment: @Vivek: Khaurs suggestion deals with that. The extra directed edge has a cost equal to the vehicle cost. The downside with his solution is that it increases the number of routes a lot. Especially considering that the added graphs will also have vehicles (although you can skip those that are slower than the one you already have). The upside is that it is generic and that it will generate good solutions. (Khaur's solution is what I would have suggested.)

Comment: @VivekRai This is the issue about the heuristic that I was mentioning.  Optimal heuristics never discard an optimal path, but usually such heuristics are also much less efficient at discarding bad paths. The case of the vehicle, a very bad short-term outcome but potentially long-term optimal outcome is typically what heuristics have trouble dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though [beam search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_search) would suit this problem. Beam search uses a heuristic function *H* and a parameter *k* and works like this:

1. Initialize the set *S* to the initial game position.
2. Set *T* to the empty set.
3. For each game position in *S*, generate all possible successor positions to *S* after one move by the marauder. (A *move* being to loot, to purchase a vehicle, to move to an adjacent city, or whatever else a marauder can do.) Add each such successor position to the set *T*.
4. For each position *p* in *T*, evaluate *H*(*p*) for a heuristic function *H*. (The heuristic function can take into account the amount of loot, the possession of a vehicle, the number of remaining unlooted cities, and whatever else you think is relevant and easy to compute.)
5. If you've run out of search time, return the best-scoring position in *T*.
6. Otherwise, set *S* to the best-scoring *k* positions in *T* and go back to step 2.

The algorithm works well if you store *T* in the form of a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) with *k* elements.

Comment: What I have posted is a subset of the original problem. It also involves some image processing stuff integrated. However, The core functions are easily visible and you can see here (http://pastebin.com/ShXNN9Ss)